# Method or application for updating files and/or applications on many remote computers?

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates, automatic-update, software-update

I have several Windows 10 and Windows 7 machines that are operating remotely. Sometimes, certain files or executables need to be updated. This would involve the following.

1. Close running program.
2. Delete its current executable
3. Copy the new executable
4. Replace (delete and copy) any files as needed
5. Relaunch the program

I was wondering if there is an application of some sort that would allow me to control this across individual systems (individual update) or across all systems (bulk update).

Answer (score 0):

First, specific software recommendations is outside the scope of *Superuser*. Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ , instead.

However, you could write a simple batch script to do this, if there is a central repository with the new files.

- Use *[taskkill](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)* to stop a running application.
- Use copy* or better, *[robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)*, to overwrite the old files with new (*robocopy* let's you specify date, to prevent overwriting *newer* files with old), specifying the full UNC path. Alternatives would be to use [FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158138/how-to-ftp-with-a-batch-file) or [SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150152/secure-ftp-using-windows-batch-script) to transfer the files. In copying the new files over the old, you've effectively deleted the old ones.
- Use the *[start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)* command to restart the application.

Of course, there are complications:

- Under whose credentials is each applications running? Your script should run under the same credentials when restarting the application -- if you always use System, then the local user would have difficulty interacting with the app. For all other purposes, the script could run as System.
- Should applications to be replaced *always* be restarted? If you want to determine if it's running at the beginning, check the results of *taskkill*, and use that to determine whether to restart.
- Using SFTP requires other applications to be installed on server and client.
- It would be *very* useful to record a log of the script's work.

Answer (score 0):

Built in to Windows are WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) and WinRM (Windows Remote Management), they both do the same thing but with different network plumbing. Also Windows can copy files to another computer the same way you copy files on a single computer.

---

This batch file will give you a text file of computers turned on on your network.

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A >> c:\computerlist.txt
```

---

To kill all instances of a process across the network

```
wmic /node:@c:\computerlist.txt process where "name='notepad.exe'" call terminate
```

---

To copy files. C$ is a hidden administrative share that only admins can use.

```
copy c:\somefolder\file.exe \\127.0.0.1\C$\Somefolder\file.exe
```

See `for /?` to see how to do above looping through *computerlist.txt*. Put following line in a batch file. Remove the echo part to actually do something.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("C:\Folder\computerlist.txt.txt") do echo copy "c:\folder\file.exe" "\\%%A\C$\folder\file.exe
```

There is no point to deleting and copying.

---

To start an invisible process on a remote computer (it will be visible if started on the local computer). Here we are specifying a single computer rather than a text file of computers.

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe"
```

---

For help type `for /?`, `wmic /?`, `wmic process get /?`, `wmic process call /?`. Also `wmic /format /?` and `wmic /node /?`.